# How to put another button in android quick search box?

Tags: android, quick-search

i'm using android qsb feature in my app. Qhen user click len button on hes keyboard, i open quick search box with one input box and one button.

I want to know if i can add another button in qsb.

I think it is possible, Google has added search by voice button in qsb.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Android built-in search facilities, like the Quick Search Box, then no you can't add your own buttons.  Only the voice search button can be added.